# How to Cleanup applications

Tags: ventura

In earlier versions of macOS there were options in Recommendations (as I remember) to cleanup but I can't seem to find it in Ventura.

My system seems to have a number of unsupported 32bit apps (imported from earlier OS).
These are shown in System Report.

How do I remove them?

---

[image]

```
CanoScan 8800F:

  Version:  13.9.2
  Obtained from:    Unknown
  Last Modified:    19/8/2009, 1:00 pm
  Kind: 32-bit (Unsupported)
  Location: /Library/Image Capture/TWAIN Data Sources/CanoScan 8800F.ds
  Get Info String:  ScanGear 8800F for Mac OS X Version 13.9.2, Copyright CANON INC. 2007-2011 All Rights Reserved
```

Comment: Can't you just go to the enclosing folder in FInder and delete the application there?

Comment: I can't find them e.g. I have *Canoscan 8800F … 32-bit(unsupported)* but it isn't in Applications

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of System Report showing the application? For me, it always shows the path to the app folder there.

Comment: That's strange, why is Microsoft AutoUpdate selected but CanoScan shown in the bottom? Nevertheless, look at the Location: string in the bottom half, that's where it's stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select a line in System Report, you can see the location of the application in question in the bottom half of the window.

[image]

Comment: I did this - in most cases I needed `rm -rf` and it took quite a while to get rid of them all.